# Changing the structure of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a function that looks something like this:

```
let result = [];
$(this).find('.js-readable').each(function(){ 
    if (this._value().length > 0){
        result.push({
            [this.mainId] : this._value()
        });
    };
});
return result
```

As result I get an array that looks like this:

```js
[{
  "dpr_name3": "3"
}, {
  "dpr_name1": "1"
}, {
  "dpr_name4": "5"
}, {
  "dpr_name2": "2"
}, {
  "dfnc_cur": "181"
}, {
  "doc_dt": "14.11.2017"
}]
```

How can I change my function to get it like this:

```js
[{
  "dpr_name3": "3",
  "dpr_name1": "1",
  "dpr_name4": "5",
  "dpr_name2": "2",
  "dfnc_cur": "181",
  "doc_dt": "14.11.2017"
}]
```

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Note that I amended your question to remove references to JSON - nothing about this is anything to do with JSON. You have an array of objects.

Comment: `let result = [{}]; result[0][this.mainId] = this._value()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to push into array. All you have to do is to initialize your array with an empty object as a first element then add key-value into it while looping:

```js
let result = [{}];
$(this).find('.js-readable').each(function(){ 
    if (this._value().length > 0){
        result[0][this.mainId] = this._value;
    };
});
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change `result` to an object and assign the values to the given keys.

```
let result = {};
$(this).find('.js-readable').each(function(){ 
    if (this._value().length > 0){
        result[this.mainId] = this._value()
    };
});
```

For later use, you could wrap the result in an array.